# jQuery - Flexslider - Is it possible to change the "minItems" / "maxItems" options during runtime (after initialization)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am trying to change these values during runtime to respond to the size of the page.

It does not seem that these values can be changed other than the initialization:

```
$(window).load(function() 
{
  $('#primary_slider').flexslider
    ({
        minItems: 1,
        maxItems: 1,
    });
```

Thanks!